# Best way to control/animate dom elements when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, animation, scroll

Are there any jQuery plugins that make it easy to control/animate dom elements based on scroll position?

Similar to the [nike better world](http://nikebetterworld.com/index) and [ben the body guard](http://benthebodyguard.com/) sites.

My actual goal is to have elements move up and fade in when scrolling down and move down and fade out when scrolling up with the animation being 1 to 1 with the scroll.

Comment: Damn, that Nike site is spiffy!

Comment: ...so why don't you check out the CSS and JavaScript behind those two sites?

Comment: @Matt I am, but am also asking around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/blog/code-tutorials/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/

This plugin was just released. Does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've never found any plugins that do it too well. If you want custom control over I'd recommend just coding something from hand. [This site](http://labs.impulsestudios.ca/a-better-way-to-sticky-content-with-javascript) has a pretty solid tutorial on the premise of it.

Comment: I agree, have a container div for each of the 'pages' (in the nike page). Your onscroll handler adjusts the (relative) positions of certain elements within each 'page'... I'm not sure what functionality OP is looking for from a plugin